# How can I access the pod when it become CrashLoopBackOff?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Right now, I deployed some pods on my kubernetes cluster. But sometime, my image may has some bugs which make the pod cannot start correctly.

For example:
nats-1                              0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   121        10h

I also cannot see any error in the kubectl log.

So is there any way to access this pod? Or is there any tools or tech can allow to to enter the container?

Thanks a lot all! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `kubectl describe` to get the events, it sometimes might show some errors there. Otherwise you can probably also make the deployment/pod run a command like `sleep 3600` to keep it open for you to exec into it to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Edited after clarification:

You could go into the worker (`kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o wide` to get which one) and access the node syslogs or pods' logs. That should show you a more detailed information of what happened.

But @ho-man approach is very valid and less cumbersome.

Comment: I can't comment others, but @ho-man approach is valid and very helpful.

Comment: If the pod cannot be created it can't go into the "CrashLoopBackOff". If the image can't be pulled it will go int "ImagePullBackOff"

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification.